# Values not display on record detail lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, governorlimits, lightning-experience

main.cmp

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:handler event="c:NavigateToDetailPage" action="{!c.NavigateComponent}" />{!v.body}
</aura:application>
```

main.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponent(
            "c:contactEdit",
            {

            },
            function(newCmp){
                if (component.isValid()) {
                    component.set("v.body", newCmp);
                }
            }
        );
    },

    NavigateComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var a = event.getParam("result");
        $A.createComponent(
            "c:contactDetailCmp",
            {
                "conObj" : event.getParam("result")
            },
            function(newCmp){
                if (component.isValid()) {
                    component.set("v.body", newCmp);
                }
            }
        );
    } 
})
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what's not working ?

Comment: is the component created successfull in both cases? what status says? Tracking status argument in a callback function helps in troubleshooting